# Is there a Selektor for JavaFx based on text or rowNum?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

i want to style JavaFx list cells based on text Value. I can do a style by even/odd (s. below)

```
.list-cell:odd {
-fx-font-size: 20;
```

}

Is there a possibility based on text, like

`.list-cell[text*='containedText''] {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}

If this is not possible, is there something like :nth-child() (this is not working). I know which childs have to be selected, so i could create the css on the fly.
`

My final goal is to style a autocomplete based on attributes of each entry.

regards
Andreas

I found a solution for styling AutoComplete Cells based on included text. But it's not very elegant. I copied the following classes:

AutoCompletePopup

AutoCompletePopupSkin

autocompletion.css

AutoCompletionBinding

AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding

In AutoCompletePopup i overwrote one method to add a CellFactory:

```
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {

    autoCompletePopupSkin = new AutoCompletePopupSkin(this);

    final ListView<T> listView = (ListView) autoCompletePopupSkin.getNode();
    listView.setCellFactory(l -> new TextFieldListCell<T>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            this.getStyleClass().remove("bold");
            if(!empty && item.toString().contains("(H)")) {
                this.getStyleClass().add("bold");
            }
        }
    });

    return autoCompletePopupSkin;
}
```

In the css i added the class with my desired styling;

```
.bold  { -fx-font: normal bold 12 serif;}
```

Thx to James_D who gave me the hint with the CellFactory!

Comment: This isn't supported by CSS in JavaFX. You can use a cell factory on the list view that generates `ListCell`s whose `updateItem(...)` or `updateIndex(...)` methods change the style class (or a `PseudoClass`) for the list cell depending on the item or index.

Comment: Thanx for comment. If you set it as an answer, i'll accept it. I read the css documentation and hoped i overlooked something. So i mustn't waste time to go further in this direction. Can you give me a hint, how do i get the ListCells of a Autocompletion which i set with TextFields.bindAutoCompletion...